# Sequelize query execution order is wrong

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hook

I have this piece of code,

and my after create hook is executing DB queries in the wrong order

```
afterCreate: async (instance1, { transaction }) => {
    const model2 = this.db.getModel('Model2');

    // PART 1
    const instance2 = await model2.findOne({
    where: { id: instance.model2Id },
    transaction,
    });

    // PART 2
    return mission.update({...}, { transaction });
}
```

When using BulkCreate(2 items) I have no idea why order of query execution is,

PART 1(first) -> PART 1(second) -> PART 2(first) -> PART 2(second).

Any hints?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, I remember, looking in the code of sequelize that they use a Promise.map in order to handle the multiple instances passed to bulkCreate. A promise.map wait for all promises to resolve. This means that the promise are executed at the same time in parallel. So the order you describe, seems logic regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not waiting for the update to finish.  Try:

```
// PART 2
    return await mission.update({...}, { transaction });
```